# How to get height and width of image with Android Universal Image Loader?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

How can I access the height and width of an image loaded using the Android Universal Image Loader?

Comment: I've never used it, but does it really not have a getWidth() and getHeight() method for your image objects??

Comment: @SiddharthLele - I don't know what you mean - I just want a number (px or dp) of the height and width of the image.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel - I don't know, but I do not see one in the instructions anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "image"? Original image cached on disc? Or Bitmap displayed in ImageView?

Comment: @NOSTRA - The main thing I'm trying to determine is the height-to-width ratio, so whether original or cached on disc, it doesn't matter (but not the area displayed in ImageView, in case that was cropped/resized...etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get Bitmap of image when image was loaded using ImageLoadingListener:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView, [options], new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
        int width = loadedImage.getWidth();
        int height = loadedImage.getHeight();
        //...
    }
});
```