# Android dialog with custom layout: not fully shown

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-dialog

I'm creating an app that shows a GridView with photos and some TextViews with details regarding the photo (uploader, description). When the user clicks on a GridView item, it is supposed to show the picture bigger with some details in TextViews (just like on Facebook when you click on an image).

That's why I decided to implement this with an Alert Dialog and a custom layout. The layout is the following, just an ImageView and a TextView to the right of the picture.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.example.handmadecommunity.FullImageActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptor"
            android:maxHeight="500dp"
            android:maxWidth="500dp"
            android:src="@drawable/test" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/picture"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I create my alert dialog the following way (just to point out, this is in a fragment, that's why the getActivity())

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_full_image, null);

TextView description = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
description.setText(desc);

alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title).setView(layout).setCancelable(true);
AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alert.show();
```

My problem can be shown on this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvtTF.jpg.

Am I missing something on the layout or code?

Comment: try defining Dummy text in your TextView android:text="Some Dummy Text" and check weather it is shown or not in layout

Comment: @L-X not shown unfortunately

Comment: I just set ImageView width and height to 500dp manually and your textView just got push off the screen Try placing it below ImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ImageView is too big it is pushing TextView out of the screen try placing it below ImageView

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Hello "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_below="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: Yes, it is shown now, thanks. How can I find out the maxHeight and maxWidth for the image in order to have the TextView to the right? Because I would like to add comments as well below it. So it would be image to the left and everything else to the right.

Comment: The way you initialize TextView ,initialize your ImageView imageView=(ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.picture); and use imageView.getWidth(); and imageView.getHeight() to make changes in your layout

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. The picture will be taken from the database and I'm using the Universal Picture Loader that's why I have the maxWidth and maxHeight. Otherwise, it would be shown in full size.

Comment: What you want to do ,can you explain in bit detail ?

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant how to find the appropriate dimensions for the image in order for the layout to be displayed correctly

Comment: The user would upload images to the server and would follow other users. So, on his wall, he would see posts of other users. More or less, like facebook. The thing is that the images would be in different sizes from different users, and I would like to display all of them in a specific size, thus the maxHeight and width

Comment: So that would create a problem becuase if you are setting textView to right of image , on small image it will work but not on big image I would suggest you to instead of using textView to set message try using alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(desc); or place TextView either to top or below the ImageView

Comment: Exactly. That's why I need to find out the max height and width in which this layout would actually work as I want it to.

Comment: Maybe this can help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331062/how-to-get-height-and-width-of-image-with-android-universal-image-loader)

Comment: thanks, but I really don't care of the uploaded image size. I just need to display all of them in the same size to have a consistent layout in my dialog.

Comment: Why don't you use Picasso Library its easier to use and you can do something like this Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(100, 100)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView);

Comment: I do the same with the Universal Image Loader by setting maxWidth and height. My problem is in the alert dialog, that pushes the TextView out of the view, instead of re sizing itself to wrap content

Comment: This will be probably because your  screenWidth is less than 500dp , because you have specified this in ImageView ,try decreasing the maxWidth attribute in ImageView, but this will result different in different screen on big screen you will have lots of area remain unused and smaller one you will face same problem that you just faced

Comment: I'm just creating this project for tablet screens. Not going to create layouts for different screens. And right now I am using an emulator of 1280x800.

Comment: Then simply use ImageView layout_width to be 500 dp and layout_height to be 500 dp , it doesn't matter what your image size is it will never go out of these bounds